# Rails 3 replace Link text with an Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble replacing my link from text to an image in my Rails app.

In my .erb view, I have:

```
<%= link_to('Up!', vote_up_article_path(article), :method => :article) %>
```

I've got an arrow image in my public/images folder but I can't seem to be able to display it instead of the Up! text.  Does anyone have any solutions that I can try?  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: i tried using image_tag('up.jpg') and all I got was text that said Up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag('up.png'), ...) %>
```

(Obviously, change `up.png` to whatever the name of the image is.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  When I look at the view, it simply displays /images/up.jpg instead of the actual arrow.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Oops, so I used image_tag and instead of an arrow, I just get the text "Up"

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work with jpgs but it works with png's.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
<%= link_to( image_tag('path_to_image_inside_public_images.jpeg'), vote_up_article_path(article), :method => :post ) %>
```

But there is no "article" method on the HTTP protocol, I believe you probably meant either **:post** or **:put**.

Comment: `image_path` will only output the path to the image, not the image html tag itself. You should use `image_tag` instead.

Comment: My bad, i thought image_tag but typed image_path.